# xcode Interface Builder background color preference

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

It seems odd, so i am likely just missing it in preferences, but how does one change the actual background color of IB in Xcode? Not any of the elements, but the actual blinding white of the standard IB? Too much contrast and when you zoom out, the view controllers almost disappear..

Thanks for any tips..

Comment: I noticed the IDEInterfaceBuilderKit.ideplugin has a class called IBCanvasBackgroundView. You may be able to make an Xcode plugin that changes this class to have a background color. When I have time, I'll try to do this if you don't find another solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've gone ahead and created an Xcode plugin that changes the background color of the storyboard editor. You can find the source at [rpendleton/xcode-canvas-color](https://github.com/rpendleton/xcode-canvas-color). I've hardcoded it to a light gray color, as shown in the screenshot below, but this can be changed easily.

(Also, I don't think you're missing a setting for it. When I decompiled Xcode, the drawRect method for the background view explicitly called `[[NSColor whiteColor] set]`.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ryan, you clearly are steps ahead of me in the Xcode world, thank YOU very kindly. I will grab the plug-in and consider you a very kind soul.. cheers.

Comment: Seriously.. everyone who has ever squinted at a complex layout in IB, especially on a 15" MacBook Pro.. get this plugin.. 
**what a difference on tired eyes!

Comment: What exactly is compile in this case? I built and archived but nothing changed. I'm having problems with white elements on a white bg

Comment: You're probably running into [Issue #3](https://github.com/ryanp-me/xcode-canvas-color/issues/3).

Comment: For Xcode 8 run this command in terminal before you compile the project: sudo codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Xcode.app

Comment: @SatnamSync Make sure you're aware of the fact that Xcode may behave oddly after removing the code signature. There are numerous reports on the Alcatraz project documenting some of these unexpected behaviors, and I can't in good conscience recommend removing the signature as a solution.

Comment: I've been working with this from quite a while, it's working just fine. There are no issue so far.

Answer (score 2):

One doesn’t. Submitting a feature request to Apple is your only hope.

Comment: and if you have an Apple Developer Account, you can submit a feature request via http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Bug: 18702673 was created.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with recent changes to Xcode, Ryan Pendleton's [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438240/947870) is no longer a viable option. (unless you are willing to break Xcode's code signing, which can be quite problematic.) However, the good news is that there is now an official solution -- so long as you are willing to upgrade to OS X 10.14 Mojave: **Upgrade to OS X 10.14 Mojave and turn on Dark mode.** When Dark Mode is enabled, the background in Interface Builder darkens to a nice, eye-pleasing dark gray color. Navigating around a large storyboard is now MUCH easier (and less eye-scorching :) )

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]