# Change Xcode's storyboard interface builder canvas colour

Tags: xcode, canvas, colors, storyboard, interface-builder

I am using Xcode 6.4 and find the canvas/background colour of the interface builder to be terrible. ViewControllers have a general whitish colour, so does the canvas. It makes viewing rather uncomfortable as there is no contrast between the canvas and the objects I work with (view controllers etc). Is there any way I could change the canvas colour please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode Interface Builder background color preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435985/xcode-interface-builder-background-color-preference)

Comment: @deej great find. Will definitely change my canvas colour. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: I think the question is a duplicate and shouldn't be answered

Comment: @deej Well Im not aware of the protocol regarding this situation. But I'm sure if your response were an answer people would find the it easier. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research into this went, there is no way to change the canvas colour.

**UPDATE**

There seems to indeed be a way to do this (thanks to deej): [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435985/xcode-interface-builder-background-color-preference)