# change storyboard background in xcode 9.0

Tags: xcode

I havn't found an answer to this dispite numerous searchs. I have a 27" monitor, when I open a main storyboard in full screen, it is all white background, it's really bad for the eyes when working at night. I need to change the white to gray or black while the drawings can still be easily visible, like white, how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode Interface Builder background color preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435985/xcode-interface-builder-background-color-preference)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible, but as an alternate solution you could invert the colors via system preferences...

**System Preferences->Accessibility->Display; Invert Colors**